# URI Representing a Single Resource with Two Possible Identifiers

Tags: rest

I have a resource that can be represented in one of two ways:

1. Big Serial Number, or
2. Small Serial Number

Is it closer adherence to REST principles to:

- A: have a query string specify the type (https://acme.org/api/widget/aaa-111-aaa?type=big vs https://acme.org/api/widget/aaa?type=small), or
- B: have query strings specify the type as search parameters (https://acme.org/api/widget?serial=aaa-111-aaa?type=big vs https://acme.org/api/widget?serial=aaa?type=small), or
- C: in the URI (https://acme.org/api/widget/big/aaa-111-aaa vs https://acme.org/api/widget/small/aaa), or
- D: something else (ex: headers)?

To me, it seems like having it in the URI (option C) specifies an entirely different resource, and in this case, they should represent the exact same resource. Is option A the best way to represent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you decide to structure your URI is not essential to REST, which is an interaction model.  If you work with web servers, and you work on a per-request basis instead of a conversation basis, you're already in the RESTful way of working.

I'm not aware of an accepted consensus on what shape of URI is preferable, and it may be a matter of opinion.  I prefer C because I see the URI path as the 'solid' part of a URI, and the query parameters as a 'temporal', per-query modification, such as requesting it in JSON instead of XML.  But ultimately, [that's just my opinion](http://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=BE&v=pWdd6_ZxX8c).  At any rate, there is no rule against having multiple URIs for the same information, so C is no less viable than the others.

StackOverflow has an interesting question and insightful answers on this: [REST API Best practices: Where to put parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters)

---

As for your IDs, I'm going to look at this problem through the lens of a hypothetical user/consumer of your URIs, which brings me to two considerations:

**Are your ID types syntactically distinguishable?**  As in, if I just give you a string, can you tell with 100% certainty which type it is?  If yes, don't distinguish between short and long; accept them both interchangeably.

```
acme.org/widget/aaa-111-aaa
acme.org/widget/aaa
```

**Does the small number need more info?**  A category, maybe?  Then you have two different paths already, and you don't need to worry about the rest (no pun intended):

```
acme.org/widget/aaa-111-aaa
acme.org/widget/dynamite/aaa
```

Comment: Presently, I would be able to tell the difference, based on pre-defined lengths of the strings (ex: I know 3 characters is the small variant and 9 characters is the big variant). In which case, the only URLs are (https://acme.org/api/widget/aaa and (https://acme.org/api/widget/aaa-111-aaa) but even though they reference the same resource, would that not make them seem like two distinct resources?

Comment: @Bullines I don't see an immediate problem with a resource being available from several URIs, but if this does present an issue I'm unaware of, you could define a preferred, canonical URI and have other entry points redirect to your preferred one.